# Application Main Entities Naming

Tags: web-applications, naming, entities

I am creating a web application aimed to business and peoples. In the beginning we decided to differentiate the two main entities for which our application will be directed to Business (for business) and User (for peoples), and I would like to know your opinions if this naming can lead to problems. We are already in an advanced stage of development, and therefore, change now would be an arduous task, so I'd better check your opinion before.

For example, following this nomenclature, we would have urls like this:

```
myapp.com/business/:businessId:
myapp.com/user/:userId:
```

Sorry if this is not in the correct stackexchange site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it would lead to problems necessarily but the convention is Business or Consumer (rather than User since they're technically both users).  B2B (business to business) or B2C (business to consumer).

Comment: But I believe that a person who is accessing our application would not like to be called _consumer_, most because the site is not for eCommerce, it's more a kind of social network, so most visitors are lay people. So we find that only _user_ would be good. :S